# Verbal question about geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a verbal question that goes:

> In one city, a vaccination campaign against Corona began.
> The number of vaccinators is 2.5% higher each week.
> In the eighth week the number of vaccinators was 9,500.
> A. How many people were vaccinated in the first week?
> B. How many people were vaccinated in total after 8 weeks?

I tried to do solve it like so:

> A:
> $$q=1.025\\a_8=9500\\a_1=?$$
> $$a_n=a_1*q^{n-1}\rightarrow(n=8)\\a_1\approx7992.019$$
> B:$$S_n=\frac{a_1(q^n-1)}{q-1}\rightarrow(n=8, a_1=7992.019, q=1.025)\\ S_8\approx69,819.204$$

Does this solution correct?
They using people as the units in the question so I'm not sure if the number should be whole.
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, your method is correct, just round the final answer down to the nearest whole number below it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.